# Jenkins Tests results available but no trend-chart

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've a jenkins pipeline script which executes rake to test a webapplication using watir an selenium.
The results are exported as XML-format in junit format.
In the post-step of the pipeline i got the following step declared:

```
always {
  junit "Tests/results/TEST-*.xml"
  archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: "Tests/results/TEST-*.png"
}
```

The test results are available in both views in jenkins "Test Results Analyzer" and in the "Test Result Trend"-chart in the Job-overview of the jenkins pipeline.

I've now created a new job which will do quite the same only for a different branch the given pipeline is also the same expect the branch to checkout but in this case, the results are available in the "Test Results Analyzer" but the is not "Test Result Trend"-chart being shown. Also the files are available on the disk where the job is executed, the folder name has not being changed.

The job has already ran for more than 5 times and have both succeeding and failing tests in the testsuite.

Any help why the "Test Result Trend" is not being shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For trends to be visible on job level, you need at least one execution without any failures. Once you have it, trends will become visible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).